# how do i write literally two words on a file and avoid data injection?

Tags: php, ajax, security, code-injection

the problem is simple. i made a small HTML5 game and since some of my friends got pretty excited with it i wanted to build a hall of fame. the idea would just be a simple csv, like

```
Name,Points,Date
AAA,15,2012-08-25
```

etc.; how do i do this? my idea was to send things with an ajax request to a php file which in turn parses and writes to the csv, but i can't really imagine how to send data to the php file without it being noticed (allowing people to input fake scores).

also, this has to be super simple, so, no node.js, etc.

Comment: You cannot stop people from sending fake requests which would in turn result in fake scores in a super simple manner. Sorry.

Comment: url:///hall.php?name=AAA&score=238947623489234723984723948237492384; no mention of SQL in my post either, please be constructive.

Comment: Is this comment directed at me (you know people can see the revision history right)?

Comment: haha i totally forgot i had written "sql" in the object; still, my bad, nowhere in the body; again, please, be constructive

Comment: My question in the comment was constructive. Please don't tell me otherwise, but instead focus on writing correct titles.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do it, as without server-side validation, it can still be faked - this is the reason most Flash games you see have ridiculous high-scores.

One method you could use is time-based encryption. This doesn't make it foolproof, but does however make it really annoying and fiddly to fake manually.

For example, you could encrypt the score, using the current timestamp in MS as the key, and send the hash and the time to the server. On the server end, you could then decrypt the hash using the time as the key. If the time is too far out from the current server time (taking time to send the score into account), discard the score.

An example request would be:

```
page.php?t={timestamp}&name={name}&h={encryptedscore}
```

Where `t` is the time in MS, `name` is the name of the user, and `h` is the hash of the time and score.

This isn't perfectly secure, but makes it a lot harder for anyone without the ability to live-edit the script to fake.

Comment: i thought about that, and i am also aware of this drawback, i just wondered whether there could have been a standard solution i'm not aware of.

Comment: Just to add to it: it would by a lot harder if you create some sort of salt as adding the user ID and/or some other data to the hash. Preferibelly spliting some info and interleaving the values.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a straight up AJAX call there is nothing to prevent anyone from opening up Fiddler and modifying the http posts that go this. 
Just validate the inputs you receive from the client. make sure a number is a number and the date is a valid date.

Are you even using SQL? SQL injection is where people take input from the client and concatenate it straight into SQL queries.

Comment: no, i'm not thinking of using SQL because i don't need it specifically ... how do i validate the inputs anyway?